# How to define props interface for Apollo's React HOC?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-apollo

I am trying to use Apollo's React HOC to fetch and pass data to my component, but I'm getting an error of:

```
Argument of type 'typeof BrandList' is not assignable to parameter of type 
'CompositeComponent<{ data?: QueryProps | undefined; mutate?: MutationFunc<{}> | undefined; }>'.
Type 'typeof BrandList' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{ data?: 
QueryProps | undefined; mutate?: MutationFunc<{}> | undefined; }>'.
Type 'typeof BrandList' provides no match for the signature '(props: { data?: 
QueryProps | undefined; mutate?: MutationFunc<{}> | undefined; } & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'.
```

My file looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {graphql} from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const BrandsQuery = gql`
  query {
    allBrands {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`

interface IBrand {
  id: string
  name: string
}

interface IData {
  loading: boolean,
  allBrands: IBrand[]
}

interface IProps {
  data: IData
}

class BrandList extends React.Component<IProps, void> {
  public render () {
    const {loading, allBrands} = this.props.data

    if (loading) {
      return (
        <div>Loading data..</div>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {allBrands.map((brand) => (
          <li>{brand.id} - {brand.name}</li>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default graphql(BrandsQuery)(BrandList)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

If I use `{}` instead of the interface, the code compiles, but then I can't use any props inside the `render` function.

EDIT:

I have tried to rewrite the last line to

```
export default graphql<any, IProps>(BrandsQuery)(BrandList)
```

which gets rid of the error, but now when I try to include the component as

```
<div>
    <BrandList />
</div>
```

I am getting following error:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<IProps>'.
Property 'data' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have solved the issue like this.. I had to add another Props interface

```
interface IExternalProps {
  id: string
}

interface IProps extends IExternalProps {
  data: IData
}

export default graphql<any, IExternalProps}>(BrandsQuery)(BrandList)
```

Basically, `IExternalProps` is the interface for props your component expects from the outside, ie. when you actually use the component in JSX, while `IProps` is the interface for props you receive via GraphQL query (HOC). This interface must extend the `IExternalProps`, Typescript then have a chance to actually type check it.

Comment: Do you mean the `graphql` HOC expects the props exposed by `IExternalProps`?

Comment: @LiauJianJie Yes.

Comment: note that where you've marked `any`, the Apollo Docs put the type of the Apollo payload : https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/static-typing.html#options